# En operaciones sobre un arreglo, muestra un resultado incorrecto luego de la primera fila del arreglo

Tags: c, array

¿Por qué al llamar a las funciones que multiplican y dividen cada uno de los elementos de las filas de un arreglo, únicamente me muestra la primera multiplicación de la primer fila del arreglo, y los demás resultados me los muestra como iguales a cero?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#define SIZE 10

void sumarFilas(double a[][SIZE], int filas_sum);
void multiplicarFilas(double b[][SIZE], int filas_mul);
void dividirFilas(double c[][SIZE], int filas_div);

int main()
{
    int num_fil,i,j;

    printf("Ingresa el numero de filas: ");
    scanf("%d",&num_fil);
    printf("\n");

    double bid_array[num_fil][SIZE];

    for(i=0; i<num_fil; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
        {
            printf("Ingresa el elemento que se encuentra en la posicion [%d][%d] del arreglo: ",i,j);
            scanf("%lf",&bid_array[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\nLos elementos ingresados al arreglo son:");
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0; i<num_fil; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
        {
          printf("     %.3lf",bid_array[i][j]); 
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    sumarFilas(bid_array, num_fil);

    printf("\n");

    multiplicarFilas(bid_array, num_fil);

    printf("\n");

    dividirFilas(bid_array, num_fil);

    printf("\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void sumarFilas(double a[][SIZE], int filas_sum)
{
    int i,j;

    double suma[filas_sum];

    for(i=0; i<filas_sum; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
        {
            suma[i] += a[i][j];
        }
    }

    printf("\nLa suma de los elementos de cada fila del arreglo bidimensional es:");
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0; i<filas_sum; i++)
    {
        printf("%lf\n",suma[i]);
    }
}

void multiplicarFilas(double b[][SIZE], int filas_mul)
{
    int i,j;

    double multiplicar[filas_mul] = {1};

    for(i=0; i<filas_mul; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
        {
            multiplicar[i] *= (b[i][j]);

        }
    }

    printf("\nLa multiplicacion de los elementos de cada fila del arreglo bidimensional es:");
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0; i<filas_mul; i++)
    {
        printf("%lf\n",multiplicar[i]);
    }
}

void dividirFilas(double c[][SIZE], int filas_div)
{
    int i,j;

    double dividir[filas_div] = {1};

    for(i=0; i<filas_div; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
        {
            dividir[i] /= c[i][j]; 
        }
    }

    printf("\nLa division de los elementos de cada fila del arreglo bidimensional es:");
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0; i<filas_div; i++)
    {
        printf("%lf\n",dividir[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Buena pregunta, poco valorada. Una pena.

Answer (score 2):

Estas inicializando mal los arreglos:

```
double multiplicar[filas_mul] = {1};
```

Aunque te pueda parecer lo contrario, ahí estás creando un arreglo en el que únicamente el primer elemento valdrá 1 mientras que el resto de posiciones serán inicializadas a 0.

Para setear correctamente el arreglo tendrás que usar un bucle:

```
for(int i=0; i<filas_mul; i++)
  multiplicar[filas_mul]=1;
```

Comment: Buena respuesta a una buena pregunta. Poco valoradas ambas.