# Problema con operaciones de elementos en un arreglo

Tags: c, funciones, array

Tengo problema al querer mostrar el resultado de la división de los elementos de cada fila de un arreglo bidimensional.

Lo que se plantea hacer es: Dividir el primer elemento de la fila de un arreglo bidimensional entre el segundo elemento de la fila, y el resultado entre el tercer elemento de la fila, para que, al acabar la fila, mostrar el resultado de esa división, el problema está que cuando corro el programa, al mostrarme el resultado de cada división en cada fila, me muestra el valor de cero, ¿Alguien podría explicarme por qué?. Ya intenté cambiar el tipo de dato y sigue ocurriendo lo mismo.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

void sumarFilas(double a[][SIZE], int filas_sum);
void multiplicarFilas(double b[][SIZE], int filas_mul);
void dividirFilas(double c[][SIZE], int filas_div);

int main()
{
    int num_fil,i,j;

    printf("Ingresa el numero de filas: ");
    scanf("%d",&num_fil);
    printf("\n");

    double bid_array[num_fil][SIZE];

    for(i=0; i<num_fil; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
        {
            printf("Ingresa el elemento que se encuentra en la posicion [%d][%d] del arreglo: ",i,j);
            scanf("%lf",&bid_array[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\nLos elementos ingresados al arreglo son:");
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0; i<num_fil; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
        {
          printf("     %.3lf",bid_array[i][j]); 
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    sumarFilas(bid_array, num_fil);

    printf("\n");

    multiplicarFilas(bid_array, num_fil);

    printf("\n");

    dividirFilas(bid_array, num_fil);

    printf("\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void sumarFilas(double a[][SIZE], int filas_sum)
{
    int i,j;

    double suma[filas_sum];

    for(i=0; i<filas_sum; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
        {
            suma[i] += a[i][j];
        }
    }

    printf("\nLa suma de los elementos de cada fila del arreglo bidimensional es:");
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0; i<filas_sum; i++)
    {
        printf("%lf\n",suma[i]);
    }
}

void multiplicarFilas(double b[][SIZE], int filas_mul)
{
    int i,j;

    double multiplicar[filas_mul];

    // Inicializamos todos los elementos del arreglo a 1.

    for(i=0; i<filas_mul; i++)
    {
        multiplicar[i] = 1;
    }

    for(i=0; i<filas_mul; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
        {
            multiplicar[i] *= (b[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\nLa multiplicacion de los elementos de cada fila del arreglo bidimensional es:");
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0; i<filas_mul; i++)
    {
        printf("%lf\n",multiplicar[i]);
    }
}

void dividirFilas(double c[][SIZE], int filas_div)
{
    int i,j;

    long double dividir[filas_div];

    // Inicializmos todos los elementos del arreglo a 1.
    for(i=0; i<filas_div; i++)
    {
        dividir[i] = 1;
    }

    for(i=0; i<filas_div; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
        {
            dividir[i] = dividir[i] / c[i][j]; 
        }
    }

    printf("\nLa division de los elementos de cada fila del arreglo bidimensional es:");
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0; i<filas_div; i++)
    {
        printf("%Lf\n",dividir[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [En operaciones sobre un arreglo, muestra un resultado incorrecto luego de la primera fila del arreglo](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40283/en-operaciones-sobre-un-arreglo-muestra-un-resultado-incorrecto-luego-de-la-pri)

Comment: Es similar, pero **no** un duplicado. Y es del mismo usuario. El fallo de aquella **no** está presente en esta.

Comment: @JesúsFragoso En la antigua pregunta no ha comentado si soluciono el problema y si lo soluciono no ha marcado la respuesta como aceptada deberías aceptar la respuesta que soluciono el problema saludos :)

Answer (score 2):

El programa sin ninguna modificación funciona bien, pero tienes un problema al dividir cada número de las filas del arreglo el resultado no es el qué esperas cómo has comentado en tu pregunta estas diviendo de manera incorrecta cada número.

**Manera incorrecta**:

```
for (i = 0; i < filas_div; i++) {
    dividir[i] = 1;
}

for (i = 0; i < filas_div; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
        dividir[i] = dividir[i] / c[i][j]; 
    }
}
```

Estas usando en la primera división como numerador el 1 evidentemente y no el primer número de la fila del arreglo cómo tu quieres, en un arreglo cómo este:

```
int arr[2][4] = {{2, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 2}};
```

El valor de la división sería: **0.0625**

El valor esperado es: **0.25**

**Manera correcta**:

```
for (i = 0; i < filas_div; i++) {
  dividir[i] = c[i][0];
}

for (i = 0; i < filas_div; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j < SIZE; j++) {
    dividir[i] /= c[i][j];
  }
}
```